# python find string between two lines, cisco route-map format

Tags: python, string, find, cisco

```
route-map other1 permit 10
route-map abc permit 10
match ip address prefix-list test
route-map abc deny 20
match ip address prefix-list test2
route-map abc permit 30
route-map other2 permit 10
```

how do i know find the route-map abc and its related config, as in:

```
route-map abc permit 10
match ip address prefix-list test
route-map abc deny 20
match ip address prefix-list test2
route-map abc permit 30
```

basically it will always start with "route-map abc" and ends with "route-map abc", however the length of lines and "permit 30" are variable, how do i find everything in between?

Comment: Maybe using Python [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for regular expressions. Try some solution and show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this: the idea is to trigger on route-map abc and switch it off on any other id. As long as it is triggered, the read lines are logged.

```
with open("route-map.txt", 'r') as f:
    routelog = f.readlines()

searchEntry = 'abc'
selected = False
outlog = []
for line in routelog:
    words = line.split()
    # probably there are other ways to find the trigger
    if len(words) > 1 and 'route-map' in words[0]:
        if searchEntry in words[1]:
            selected = True
        else:
            selected = False
    if selected:
        outlog.append(line)

print(outlog)
```